# Excel : Find Ultimate and Penultimate Values for Unique Id

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to be able to calculate the difference between the latest (ultimate) and next latest (penultimate) date for a condition (UID). I can get the latest using `MAXIFS` but need some help on getting the penultimate date.

For example, blue = source and orange = expected results:

[image: Example image]

(Apologies don't have the rep to post an image directly)

Comment: Please add logic to your explanation to explain `Dave` who does not have a penultimate date in the original table, but does in your results.

Comment: Dave is included for diversity....and also as it's possible there will only be one date :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date and time is represented by number where the integer part represent date and part after decimal represent time. [More about date in Excel.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-systems-in-excel-e7fe7167-48a9-4b96-bb53-5612a800b487)

So basically you are looking for the largest and second largest number. Use formula [`LARGE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/large-function-3af0af19-1190-42bb-bb8b-01672ec00a64?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

```
Ultimate=LARGE(Table1[Date]*(Table1[UID]=[@UID]),1)
Penultimate=LARGE(Table1[Date]*(Table1[UID]=[@UID]),2)
```

**If you are using one of these:** Excel for Microsoft 365 Excel for Microsoft 365 for Mac Excel for the web Excel for iPad Excel Web App Excel for iPhone Excel for Android tablets Excel for Android phones.  or newer.

Just use these formulas.
[image: Newer Excel versions]

**In older Excel version:** You have to input it as [array formula](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7).

It must must be confirmed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`. if you done it correctly the formula will be wrapped in `{}`. This means that formula is computed as array formula.
[image: Older Excel versions]

How it works:

1. `(Table1[UID]=[@UID])` Returns matrix of TRUE or FALSE for with same
   size as `Table1[UID]` column.
2. `Table1[Date]*(Table1[UID]=[@UID])` date column is multiplied by result formula from `1.` Excel works with boolean values this way `TRUE = 1`, `FALSE = 0`. Result of this step is matrix with number values where all rows where UID is different from `[@UID]` are `0`
3. Finally the LARGE formula finds n-th largest value from result of previous step. You get number represent date (format it as date)

There are a few caveats:

- When there is no Ultimate/Penultimate time for UID you get `0`. Use IF function to treat this exceptions.
- If there are two same most recent dates for one UID in Table1, the Penultimate time will be same as Ultimate (1st largest and 2nd largest value are same)

Comment: Thanks! This works for me and learnt more from your answer than just my original question :)